Problema en visualizar los mensajes de la DB con vue 3
buenas, espero que estén bien, estoy haciendo un chat y tengo problemas para visualizar los mensajes, estoy usando laravel 9, vue 3, laravel echo, pusher.js, laravel-websockets e inertia.js, como ya comente, no se me visualizan los mensajes y no tengo idea cual es el error ya que si se me envían los mensajes pero no se visualizan en la console me sale este error 
Tengo el siguiente codigo en el front-end:
<template>
<div class="chat">
    <div class="scrollable">
        <template v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id">
            <div v-if="user && message.user && user.id && message.user.id">
    <div class="message message-receive" v-if="user.id != message.user.id">
        <p>
            <strong class="">
                {{ message.user.name }} :
            </strong>
            {{ message.message }}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="message message-send" v-else>
        <p>
            <strong class="">
                {{ message.user.name }} :
            </strong>
            {{ message.message }}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
        </template>
    </div>

    <div class="">
        <input id="btn-input" type="text" name="message" class="" placeholder="Type your message here..." v-model="newMessage" @keyup.enter="addMessage">

        <span class="">
            <button class="" id="btn-chat" @click="addMessage">
                Send message
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>

import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
export default{
    props:['user'],
    setup(props){
        let messages = ref([]);
        let newMessage = ref('');
        onMounted(() =>{
            fetchMessages();
        });

        

        

        Echo.private('chat-channel')
          .listen('SendMessage', (e) => {
            messages.value.push({
              message: e.message.message,
              user: e.user
            });
        })



        const fetchMessages = async()=> {
            axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
                messages.value = response.data;
            });
        };

        const addMessage = async()=> {
            let user_message = {
                user: props.user,
                message: newMessage.value
            };
            messages.value.push(user_message);
            axios.post('/messages', user_message).then(response => {
              console.log(response.data);
            });
            newMessage.value = '';
        };

        

        

        return {
            messages,
            newMessage,
            addMessage,
            fetchMessages,
        }
    }
}

Y en el back-end tengo esto:
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}


public function chat(){
    return Inertia::render('Message/Show');
}

public function messages(){
    return Message::with('user')->get();
}

public function messageStore(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::user();

    $messages = $user->messages()->create([
        'message' => $request->message
    ]);

    broadcast(new SendMessage($user, $messages))->toOthers();

    return 'message sent';
}

}
Y pues quisiera saber si ustedes saben cual es el error, porque intente con otros codigos pero igual me daba error :'v

Hola Crees, para evitar recibir votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea cerrada, editala y agrega los mensajes de error como texto.
